# linq to sql, want to retrieve data from sql server and storing in a List

Tags: linq-to-sql, datacontext, using

```
public partial class LogEntriesField
{
    public static List<keyValueList> getAllFields()
    {
        using (LogEntryDataModel DB = new LogEntryDataModel())
        {                                
            var LogEntries = from field in DB.
                            select field;
            return LogEntries.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Error 1 'ssiLinq.LogEntryDataModel' does not contain a definition for 'LogEntries' and no extension method 'LogEntries' accepting a first argument of type 'ssiLinq.LogEntryDataModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

LogEntries is the table of my database DB. But why i am getting this error?

My main aim is to retrieve all key and its value in List from the table in DB.

Comment: Is your linq2sql model in a different project? If so, have you added a reference and using statement to this project?

Comment: yes Paul, i have added the reference.

Comment: Any help on this issue...